# grepl help in R

Tags: r, regex

I have a large dataset. In the dataset there are a bunch of names, but for reasons in how the data was entered I only need the names with one word in them. I was thinking of using grepl to grab any blank spaces in the words but I would also need to do this for "-". I need only observations with one word in this variable. So far

`more_than_one_word <- mydata[grepl("\s", mydata$City) , ]`

doesn't pick up anything like "Sussie James." What else can I do? Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide some of the data?

Comment: Does `mydata[grepl("^\\w+$", mydata$City) , ]` work?

Comment: If you were trying to identify a space character, the pattern would be "\\s":  `grepl("\\s", c("test", "test with space") )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take the approach of saying "Give me any string that's just letters!"

```
> vec = c(" ", "hi", "Chicago", "new york", "New_York")
> vec
[1] " "        "hi"       "Chicago"  "new york" "New_York"
> grep("^[a-zA-Z]*$", vec)
[1] 2 3
```

This will accept any string that is just letters from the first character to the last.

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
only_one_word <- mydata[which(!grepl(" |-", mydata$City)), ]
```

Example:

```
cities <- c("Los Angeles", "New York", "Chicago", "Aix-en-Provence")
#> cities[which(!grepl(" |-",cities))]
#[1] "Chicago"
```

That's if you need to remove any entry with a hyphen, too.

```
#> cities[which(!grepl(" ",cities))]
#[1] "Chicago"         "Aix-en-Provence"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can actually omit the `which` since R allows logical indexing (i.e. `cities[1:3] == cities[c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)]`

Comment: True, but I think that every programmer has certain preferences. I find the code with `which` clearer, but that's just my personal opinion.

Comment: Sure but I think it's actually not good practice. `grepl` converts numbers (output of grep) to logical, when `which` converts logical back to numbers.That's spaghetti code.

Comment: Let's not get too excited about it. The function `which()` requires a logical argument, which is provided in this case. It returns a number that is not simply a conversion from logical back to numerical (i.e., 0,1), but the element number. Extracting the relevant element number is the primary purpose of the code.

Comment: `which` has the advantage in some cases over a naked logical expression in that it removes NAs. `grepl` has the same advantage. The only got'cha I have discovered for the use of `which` is trying to use it with a "negation" (`-`) which will sometimes bite. Generally the loss of efficiency is trivial and I happen to like it for selection operations (although I don't generally mix them.)